# Extract Django Project Label in Imported File

Tags: python, django

I am implementing a meta application and have the following problem:

(root)/global.py

```
class Model(Base):
  def f(self):
    app_label = do_magic()
    return app_label
```

(root)/project/(app_label)/model.py

```
from global import global

m = Model()
print m.f()
```

for example calling `m.f()` in the file (root)/project/test/model.py should return `test`, whereas `project.test` is added to the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `do_magic` I named it `get_app_name`.  The following should be what you need.

```
import os
import inspect

def get_app_name():
    return os.path.dirname(
               os.path.abspath(
                   inspect.stack()[-1][1])).split(os.path.sep)[-1]
```

Comment: thanks! depending on the context, the number of the stack element must be replaced: inspect.stack()[i][1] (i = 2 in my case)